# How to load RadEditor content from dropdownlist value selected in a modalPopUpExtender

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using Visual studio 2005 with AjaxControlToolkit
I have a aspx page with a ModalPopupExtender. I have two DropDownList, when user selects value from first DropDownList, the second load and user can select the value from the second DropDownList. The thing is, that when second value is selected, I have to load the content of a RadEditor (from oracle 11g table) what i'm trying to do is to be able to keep the value, index of the second DropDownList, to load radEditor content, but everytime the actual page, modalPopUpupExtender is in postBack I lose the second DropDownList value. I've tried with a WebService and then to be able to load the RadEditor content, I've tried the BehaviorID property of CascadingDropDown but I was not able to call the webMethod to load the RadEditor content, i dont know how to get the value of the second DropDownList.
This is my aspx code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeLstCandidat" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnLstCandidat"
                PopupControlID="pnlLstCandidat" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="True"
                CancelControlID="ibFermerpnlLstCandidat" Enabled="True" DynamicServicePath="" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAssignerLettre" runat="server" Style="display: none" meta:resourcekey="Button8Resource1" />
            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeAssignerModeleLettre" BehaviorID="mpeLettreBehavior"
                runat="server" TargetControlID="btnAssignerLettre" PopupControlID="plnAssignerLettre"
                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="True" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlDrag"
                DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" />
            <asp:Panel ID="plnAssignerLettre" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup"
                Width="900px" EnableViewState="false">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TC_LettreCand" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
                            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TP_ListeLettreCand" runat="server" HeaderText="TP_TableReference">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Liste&nbsp;
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TP_Formulaire" runat="server" HeaderText="TP_LettreCand">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    Formulaire&nbsp;
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <asp:FormView ID="fvLettreCand" runat="server" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Justify"
                                        AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="ModeleLettreID" CssClass="SkinCJM" meta:resourcekey="fvTraitementResource1">
                                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">                                                   <%--------------------------CascadingDropDow Liste utilisant des WebServices--%>
                                                    <td align="left" style="width: 20%" class="css_detailViewHeaderStyle">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" SkinID="skin_lblform" Text="Type :"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="left" style="width: 80%" class="css_detailViewHeaderStyle">
                                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_TypeLettreListe" runat="server" />
                                                        <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccd1_Type" runat="server" ServicePath="ModeleLettre_WebService.asmx"
                                                            ServiceMethod="ChercherTypesLettre" TargetControlID="ddl_TypeLettreListe" Category="Type"
                                                            PromptText="--Choisir type--" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" style="width: 20%" class="css_detailViewHeaderStyle">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" SkinID="skin_lblform" Text="Modele :"></asp:Label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="left" style="width: 80%" class="css_detailViewHeaderStyle">
                                                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="tt" runat="server">
                                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_modLettreListe" runat="server" Enabled="false" OnDataBinding="onDatabinding_Modlettre"
                                                                    AutoPostBack="true">
                                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                                <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="CascadingDropDown1" runat="server" ServicePath="ModeleLettre_WebService.asmx"
                                                                    ServiceMethod="GetModForType" TargetControlID="ddl_modLettreListe" ParentControlID="ddl_TypeLettreListe"
                                                                    Category="Modele" PromptText="--Choisir modèle--" UseContextKey="true" LoadingText="...chargement"
                                                                    BehaviorID="BehIDAssignerLettre" />
                                                            </ContentTemplate>
                                                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

                                                        <script type="text/javascript">

                                                                 function pageLoad(sender, args){
                                                                   if($get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plnAssignerLettre") != null ){
                                                                    var sel = $get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TC_LettreCand_TP_Formulaire_fvLettreCand_ddl_modLettreListe");
                                                                    var sv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
                                                                    var test = "test"
                                                                    alert(sv);
                                                                    if ($get("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TC_LettreCand_TP_Formulaire_fvLettreCand_ddl_modLettreListe") != null) {

                                                                           var Mycdd = $find("BehIDAssignerLettre");  
                                                                         alert("après l'appele de behavior");
                                                                         alert(sel);
                                                                         alert(sv);
                                                                         alert(document.getElementById('<%=  fvLettreCand.clientID %>'));

                                                                  } }
                                                                 }

                                                                 function onPopulated(sv, forme)  
                                                                 {  
                                                                   ModeleLettre_WebService.GetContenuLettre(sv, forme, OnComplete, OnError, OnTimeOut);
                                                                 } 

                                                                 function OnComplete(arg)
                                                                 {
                                                                    alert(arg);
                                                                 }

                                                                 function OnTimeOut(arg)
                                                                 {
                                                                    alert("timeOut has occured");
                                                                 }

                                                                 function OnError(arg)
                                                                 {
                                                                    alert("error has occured: " + arg._message);
                                                                 }
                                                        </script>

                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
 <tr>
                                                    <td align="left" style="width: 12%" class="css_detailViewHeaderStyle" valign="top">
                                                        <asp:Label ID="LbContenu" runat="server" SkinID="skin_lblform" Text="Contenu :"></asp:Label></td>
                                                    <td align="left" style="width: 70%" class="css_detailViewHeaderStyle">
                                                        <telerik:RadEditor ID="reContenu" runat="server" EditModes="Design, Html" EnableTheming="True"
                                                            Width="100%" Language="fr-FR" Content='<%# Bind("Contenu") %>'>
                                                            <CssFiles>
                                                                <telerik:EditorCssFile Value="~/App_Themes/ThemeCJM/HTMLEditor.css" />
                                                            </CssFiles>
                                                            <Tools>
                                                                <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Bold" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Italic" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Underline" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="ForeColor" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyLeft" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyCenter" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyRight" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyFull" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyNone" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Indent" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Outdent" />
                                                                </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                                                                <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Undo" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Redo" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Copy" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Cut" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="Paste" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="PasteFromWord" />
                                                                </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                                                                <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertLink" />
                                                                    <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertImage" />
                                                                </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                                                            </Tools>
                                                            <Content>
                                                            </Content>
                                                        </telerik:RadEditor>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
```